# Why do String.includes acts different with space characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So, I have this method to check if an object has a specific status:

```js
export const verifyStatus = (productStatus: string, expectedStatus: string): boolean => {
  return productStatus.split(' ').some((status) => expectedStatus.includes(status));
};
```

I'll use this as my values:

```js
const productStatus = 'POTATO BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
const expectedStatus = 'EGG'
```

The weird thing is, this is false:

```js
'POTATO BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
    .split(' ')
    .some((status) => 'EGG'.includes(status));
```

This is true (notice the double space between POTATO and BANANA)

```js
'POTATO  BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
    .split(' ')
    .some((status) => 'EGG'.includes(status));
```

But this is working despite any double space (true if I add EGG to my first string and false if I remove):

```js
'POTATO BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
    .split(' ')
    .some((status) => status.includes('EGG'));
```

```js
'POTATO  BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
    .split(' ')
    .some((status) => status.includes('EGG'));
```

Why is that happening? Am I missing something? I had this method for about 5 months and it was working perfectly until a few hours ago.

Comment: It's becasse `"EGG".includes("")` is `true`. When you run into this kind of thing, I suggest stepping through it in a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: The code using `"EGG".includes(status)` and the code using `status.includes("EGG")` are doing **very** different things. Do you really want substring matches at all?

Answer (score 1):

`"EGG".includes("")` is `true`. `"".includes("EGG")` is `false`. That's why you get different results from the two versions of your code.

Why `""`? Because `.split(" ")` on a string containing two spaces in a row will put a blank string in the array:

```js
console.log("TEST  ING".split(" "));
```

You can tell `split` to split on any **sequence** of spaces using a regular expression -- `.split(/ +/)` for just spaces, or `.split(/\s+/)` for runs of whitespace:

```js
console.log(
    "POTATO  BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE"
        .split(/\s+/)
        .some((status) => "EGG".includes(status))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(status) => 'EGG'.includes(status)` is asking whether the value of `status` is found *somewhere* in the string `'EGG'`. The empty string `''` resulting from the double space is obviously found there in several places.

If you just want to check whether `EGG` is among the space-separated items, you should use `Array.includes`:

```
'POTATO  BANANA TOMATO LETTUCE'
    .split(' ')
    .includes('EGG')
```